# "Avec" vs "à" for tools?

Tags: grammaire

Here are two example sentences:

> Ne frappez jamais directement avec un marteau sur le palier!
>
> On ne peut pas retirer la peinture au marteau et au ciseau.

One uses *avec* and the other uses *au*. Why? Is one of these wrong? I believe I also see *de* used in some cases for the conjunction when referring to a tool.

What rule operates over this? Which word should be used to translate something like "he hit it *with* a hammer" or "I cut the ham *with* my knife" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Avec* and *à* are generally not interchangeable. There are many cases where ***à*** is not used and some rarer where ***avec*** is not.

E.g.:

> *<s>Manger aux baguettes</s>* vs *manger avec des baguettes*
>
> *<s>Laver le linge avec les mains</s>* vs *laver le linge à la main*

With ***à***, only ***le*** or ***la*** can be used while ***un[e]*** and ***ce/cette*** can follow ***avec***, :

> - *découpé au ciseau*
> - *<s>découpé à un ciseau</s>*
> - *<s>découpé à ce ciseau</s>*

while

> - *découpé avec le ciseau*
> - *découpé avec un ciseau*
> - *découpé avec ce ciseau*

While *avec un[e]* flatly states what is used to do something, *au / à la* more describes a technique, a specific way to do something, sometimes an art, a craftsmanship.

Compare:

> *Moulé à la louche*

and

> *Moulé avec une louche*

or

> *Massacre à la tronçonneuse*

and

> *Massacre avec une tronçonneuse*

For this reason *ne frappez jamais directement au marteau sur le palier* is dubious.

Here is an excellent article about this subject from which I picked some examples:

[A la hache ou avec la hache ? Représentation mentale, expérience située et donation du référent](http://www.persee.fr/doc/lfr_0023-8368_1991_num_91_1_6202)

Comment: Wow, that article is reallllly comprehensive and reallllly hard to understand.

Comment: The first line in the list labeled *Les déterminants* under *Le domaine de l'instrumental* says `Abbatre A (la + *une + *cette) hache / AVEC (la + une + cette) hache`. But you've said *un/une/ce/cette* can't follow *à*. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Both that line and my reply agree. The *'s mark incorrect forms.

Comment: and if that convention is not known, the linked article is incomprehensible.

Comment: Ah...that helps a lot. Thank you. I was having a very hard time understanding it. I *thought* that might be what it meant, but it wasn't written anywhere.

Comment: I tend to say that "à/au" stands for "à coup de". Well for scissors, that sounds weird, but the idea seems to be there (just translate/adapt otherwise "à coup de" to the tool used).